# Using "using" for a button that opens a new interface

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I wrote in the help file of a software application:

> After the page has loaded, you can apply a filter to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter. You can also manually select the desired sections or refine the output of a filter by using **'Manual Selection'**

Actually, **Manual Selction** is just the label of a button on which if the user clicks a new form is opened and the manual selection is preformed through this form. So I would like to know if my sentence convey this meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replacing the word *using* with *clicking*.

Also, it is always good practice to provide images in technical documentation to help with the explanation.